# How to get the authenticated user id with php websockets server?

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

I have a web application, where my user is already authenticated within HTTP. After HTTP authentication I want to receive video calls. For this task, I've selected a WebSockets server (I wrote a small PHP CLI script).

There is a problem, that I can't find a way to authenticate the authenticated user on my WebSocket daemon. (Because it's CLI application, it works with many users per instance.)

I thought, it would be a good idea to get the headers the user sent in the handshake request to my WebSocket server. I parsed the cookies and created a session with `session_id()` and `session_start()`, but I can't do this stuff for several users, only for one.

On many boards there is advice to send the user id and some key via JS to identity the user, but it's not secure. Maybe I can send the user id with a hashed user password, which I will store somewhere in html (js inline constant)? What do you think?

What is the best way to authenticate a user on a WebSocket server? Remember, that this user is already authenticated with HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you leave their password alone.  Do not pass it through the WebSockets connection.  Once the user has been authenticated through any one means, do not use their password any more.

You're right that you can not use `session_start()` for multiple users in the same instance of the server.  Instead, you have to store the user's data separately and associate it with their TCP socket handle. (The TCP socket handle is the value returned by `socket_accept()`).

For instance, in your WebSockets server, have a user class where you can instantiate a new object for each connection.  This user object will hold their state while they're connected.

After the user authenticates to your web application, send a unique, [cryptographically secure token](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) in the HTTP response, either in the HTTP header, or in the body such as in the property of an element in the HTML head, as an assigned value in Javascript, or wherever makes sense for you.  Also store this unique value somewhere that your WebSockets server can access, along with which user it is assigned to and a timestamp.

In the client side Javascript, once the WebSockets connection is established, send the secure token.

On the server side, simply compare the token to the one that your web scripts stored and ensure that the timestamp is recent.  This will tell you which user has just logged in and allows you to pull their preferences out of the database.

A note on timestamp expiration:  WebSockets is meant to be a real-time communications system, and in most cases, the WebSockets connection is established during page load or shortly after the `onload` event.  Unless you are waiting for user interaction before opening the WebSockets connection, it does not make sense to accept a token that is older than a couple minutes.  To avoid session hijacking attempts, please only accept the first connection to use a particular token, and don't accept old tokens.

Once they're connected, you can be at least as certain of the user's identity as if you were using the $_SESSION variable for as long as they stay connected.  (TCP hijacking can occur, but the attacker would already have had a MITM attack going on, and their PHP session would have been completely compromised long before the TCP hijacking starts.)